How to inject a ViewModel Factory with parameters using Koin?
I'm trying to inject a ViewModel Factory with parameters using Koin but couldn't find a way. I read the documentation, and I saw only the Fragment Factory stuff.
I was trying to replicate what I do with Kodein (code below)
ViewModelFactory
class ViewModelFactory(
    private val context: Context,
    private val apiClient: ApiClientClass
    private val localDatabase: RoomDatabase
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {

        when {
            modelClass.isAssignableFrom(AViewModel::class.java) -> {
                return AViewModel(
                    context,
                    apiClient,
                    localDatabase
                ) as T
            }

            modelClass.isAssignableFrom(BViewModel::class.java) -> {
                return BViewModel(
                    context,
                    apiClient,
                    localDatabase
                ) as T
            }

            else -> {
                Timber.e("IllegalArgumentException Unknown class name. Add view model to your factory class!")
                throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown class name. Add view model to your factory class!")
            }
        }
    }
}

ApplicationClass
class ApplicationClass: Application(), KodeinAware {
    override val kodein by Kodein.lazy {
        import(androidXModule(this@ApplicationClass))
        bind() from singleton { ApiClient() }
        bind() from singleton {
            val build = Room.databaseBuilder(
                applicationContext,
                SomeDatabase::class.java,
                SomeDatabase.DATABASE_NAME
            )
            build.fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build()
        }
        bind() from singleton { SomeRepository(instance()) }
        bind() from provider {
            ViewModelFactory(
                this@ApplicationClass, // Context
                instance(), // ApiClient
                instance() // RoomDatabase
            )
        }
    }
}

ActivityClass
import org.kodein.di.KodeinAware
import org.kodein.di.android.kodein
import org.kodein.di.generic.instance

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), KodeinAware {
    override val kodein by kodein()

    private val factory: ViewModelFactory by instance()
    private val viewModel: AViewModel by viewModels { factory }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // some code
    }
}

